# Scaling image from the center (fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to scale an image using the `centeredScaling: true` option when setting up the Image instance. I have Circle object that is a "on" a slider that is supposed to be the scale.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/hellatan/tk1qs8ty/

A couple things:
1. it doesn't scale from the center
2. the starting point of the Circle object doesn't correlate correctly scaling the image properly (i'm guessing i'll have to adjust some math for this one, though)

Anyone have any clues as to what I'm doing wrong (mainly #1, #2 would be a bonus to know too).

Don't mind the sloppiness of the code =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the origin for x and y to center, and adjust the initial x and y of the image

```
imgInstance.set({
        scaleY: imgH / origH,
        scaleX: imgW / origW,
        originX: "center", 
        originY: "center"
    });
```

Comment: ah, thanks ben. That seemed to do the trick. I guess I was hoping that I wouldn't have to reset the left/top coords but that does not seem to be the case. i'll mark this as the answer since that was the primary goal for what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hack I've seen around, basically it translates points to and from center in a wrapper for scaling/rotating.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywu45fpd/**

Functions to translate points

```
fabric.Object.prototype.setOriginToCenter = function () {
    this._originalOriginX = this.originX;
    this._originalOriginY = this.originY;

    var center = this.getCenterPoint();

    this.set({
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        left: center.x,
        top: center.y
    });
};

fabric.Object.prototype.setCenterToOrigin = function () {
    var originPoint = this.translateToOriginPoint(
    this.getCenterPoint(),
    this._originalOriginX,
    this._originalOriginY);

    this.set({
        originX: this._originalOriginX,
        originY: this._originalOriginY,
        left: originPoint.x,
        top: originPoint.y
    });
};
```

New method on `canvas`:

```
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Canvas.prototype, {

  _scale: function(e, target, value) {
    var scale = value,
        needsOriginRestore = false;

    if ((target.originX !== 'center' || target.originY !== 'center') && target.centeredRotation) {
      target.setOriginToCenter(target);
      needsOriginRestore = true;
    }

    target.animate({ scaleX: scale, scaleY: scale }, {
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutQuad,
      onComplete: function() {
        if (needsOriginRestore) {
          target.setCenterToOrigin(target);
        }

        target.setCoords();

      },
    })

    canvas.renderAll();
  },

});
```

See `mouse:up` on fiddle for usage (basically `canvas._scale(e, target, 2)`)

The same wrapper can be applied for rotating.

Answer (score -1):

First step we are adding scale after calling the center of image.
And then scale will be of center:

```
imgInstance.scale(my_value).center().setCoords()
```